# codeSourcery G++ Lite Edition is a freeware?

Tags: g++, arm, gnu, gnu-make, coldfire

codeSourcery G++ Lite Edition is a freeware or Sharware? any help please? please
see the link "http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite_edition.html"

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these - it's actually open source